# Using django channels allowed_hosts_only with class based consumers

Tags: python, django, django-channels

From [the docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#security), `allowed_hosts_only` is a decorator to make sure the connection origin is in `settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS`. However I'm having difficulty applying it to a class based consumer. The [applying decorators](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#applying-decorators) sections explains how to add decorators to the class:

```
from channels.generic.websockets import JsonWebsocketConsumer
from channels.security.websockets import allowed_hosts_only

class MyConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    ...
    def get_handler(self, *args, **kwargs):
        handler = super(MyConsumer, self).get_handler(*args, **kwargs)
        return allowed_hosts_only(handler) # just 'return handler' works
```

This is the error I get:

```
[2017/08/14 02:32:05] WebSocket HANDSHAKING / [123.123.123.123:12345]
[2017/08/14 02:32:05] WebSocket DISCONNECT / [123.123.123.123:12345]
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 804, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 175, in run
    worker.run()
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/worker.py", line 123, in run
    raise ValueError("You cannot DenyConnection from a non-websocket.connect handler.")
ValueError: You cannot DenyConnection from a non-websocket.connect handler.
```

How should I be validating the connection origin with a class based consumer?

I thought `AllowedHostsOnlyOriginValidator` might be a mixin, but the source simply has `allowed_hosts_only = AllowedHostsOnlyOriginValidator`.

Answer (score 0):

You have check the channel for being a websocket. You can do this by checking the name of the [Channel](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#ref-channel). You find that instance on the [Message](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#ref-message). When the name is *websocket.connect* you decorate the handler with the [allowed_hosts_only](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#decorators) decorator.

This is how your `get_handler` should look like:

```
  def get_handler(self, message, **kwargs):
    handler = super(KioskConsumer, self).get_handler(message, **kwargs)
    if self.message.channel.name == "websocket.connect":
      handler = allowed_hosts_only(handler)
    return handler
```

Comment: just dumping a code block is not the quality we expect. Explain what this code does, please.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, it was not my intention, I just don't have the time to meet the quality you expect and I'm just offering my small knowledge for free. Could you read the question first? There is method called `get_handler` and the error says `ValueError: You cannot DenyConnection from a non-websocket.connect handler` As any programmer can see from my code, it is only a new conditional to fulfill the requirement.

Comment: No problem, I have taken the opportunity to explain what your code does.